# Built a list of functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I post simple code in order to understand how solve my problem. The while loop have 2 cycle but in real case have billion cycle.

```
def uno_trov():
          if(1==1):
                   return True
          else:
               return False
def due_trov():
               if(1==0):
                        return True
               else:
                   return False

condizioneV = []
condizione = [1, 0] #1 or 0 inside can be change by the user
first_time = False
i=0
while(i<2):
     if(first_time == False): #whit the first cycle I build condizioneV (list of functions)
                        if(condizione[0]==1):
                                             condizioneV.append(uno_trov)
                        if(condizione[1]==1):
                                             condizioneV.append(due_trov)
                        first_time = True
                        print(condizioneV) #I expect [True]
                        i+=1
     else: #second time condizioneV is already builded and I suppose the process will be more fast because the code not check anymore " if(condizione[1]==1)"
          print(condizioneV) #I expect [True]
          i+=1
#problem is that I obtain "[<function uno_trov at 0x0272DED0>]" two time.
```

I don't understand the reason but I obtain "[]" two time. They aren't error but I didn't have a list with one or two True/False.

Comment: You are appending _function_, not _result of function call_. Try `condizioneV.append(uno_trov())`.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

```
 condizioneV.append(uno_trov)
```

appends the function address you're missing the `()`

correction:

```
condizioneV.append(uno_trov())
```

General remark: your code is very poorly written and confusing. look at your `first_time` condition which is reversed for instance. And the indentation is terrible.

Comment: `if(1==1):` is my favorite

Answer (score 0):

That's some pretty convoluted code you have there. I can't imagine what it is trying to do. I'll presume you are a beginner.

But the reason your arrays contains functions is that these two lines are appending the functions themselves into the arrays, the functions are not being executed.

Instead of this:

```
                                     condizioneV.append(uno_trov)
                                     condizioneV.append(due_trov)
```

You need to do this:

```
                                     condizioneV.append(uno_trov())
                                     condizioneV.append(due_trov())
```

Comment: Duke thanks. To resolve the other problem? Above i post the code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a solution to one cycle but if you try to use it by pass a parameter to a function doesn't work anymore. I add "t=i" in the first if:

```
def uno_trov(t):
          if(1==t):
                   return True
          else:
               return False
def due_trov():
          if(1==0):
                   return True
          else:
               return False

condizioneV = []
condizione = [1, 1] #1 or 0 inside can change by the user
first_time = False
i=0
while(i<2):
     if(first_time == False): #whit first cycle I build condizioneV
                        if(condizione[0]==1):
                                             t=i
                                             condizioneV.append(uno_trov(t))
                        if(condizione[1]==1):
                                             condizioneV.append(due_trov())
                        first_time = True
                        print(condizioneV) #I expect [False]
                        i+=1
                        t=i
     else: #second time condizioneV is already build but not properly work good
          print(condizioneV) #I expect [True] but instead I get [False]
          i+=1
          t=i
```

In other words I would like that with first cycle I build the list of functions and from the second cycle to the end, execute the list of functions.